# Compile a .tex file in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, pdf-generation, latex, pdflatex

im making a .bat file to compile a .tex file to pdf, when i run it directly the .bat file it works fine, but when i run it in c# the error "pdflatex: invalid argument" appers

```
static void ExecuteCommand()
{
    Process p1 = new Process();
    p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\batch.bat";
    p1.StartInfo.Arguments =@"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\prueba.tex"; 
    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    try
    {
        p1.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(e); 
    }           
}
```

Please help me :(, i dont know what else to do, this is the .bat file

```
pdflatex prueba.tex
```

pause

Comment: You batch file and the command you're running in C# are not the same, so that would be a place to start debugging.  When you use the full path to prueba.tex file, does it need to be enclosed in quotation marks?  That would be the first thing I would try.  `p1.StartInfo.Arguments =@""c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\prueba.tex"";`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have spaces in the directory names, you need to enclose them in quotes

```
p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"\"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\batch.bat\"";
p1.StartInfo.Arguments =@"\"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\prueba.tex\"";
```

Alternatively change the working directory to **c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex** before running.